# How to change icon or icon color on kendo ui grid filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

when I filtering kendo grid I need to change color of "watering can" that showing above columns. So I found way to run my code on filtering event:

```
var originalFilter = self.object.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter;
    self.object.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter = function(e) {
    if(e != undefined && e != null) {
        var selector = 'th[data-field=' + e.filters[0].field + '] > a > span.k-filter';
        $(selector).css('background-color', 'red');
        return originalFilter.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

So, in such way I can change background color of icon.
But I have two problems:
1) After filtering value disappear.
2) I need to change b-color on red when some value interred in filter input, and white b-color when value is empty.
So, could you please give me example of code that will change color of filter icon.

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the following CSS style:

```
.k-icon.k-filter {
    background: url('path to your image');
}
```

to change it globally or for limiting it to one grid with `id` equal to `my_grid`, do:

```
#my_grid .k-icon.k-filter {
    background: url('path to your image');
}
```